# Unable to change config file with sed using groups and multiple lines

Tags: sed, regular-expression, configuration

I'm trying to script changes in a config file (`/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`), which boils down to:

```
[Update already installed software]
Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
Action=org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages
ResultActive=yes

[Printer administration]
Identity=unix-group:lpadmin;unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
Action=org.opensuse.cupspkhelper.mechanism.*
ResultActive=yes

[Disable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=no
```

I'm trying to set `ResultActive=yes` for all blocks that start with `[Disable hibernate`. Using sed and regex groups I came up with:

`sed -i 's/\(Disable hibernate.*\n.*\n.*\nResultActive\=\)no/\1yes/' /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`

However this does not change the file. According to [regexr](https://regexr.com/), the regex matches, but checking with [sed.js.org](https://sed.js.org/), sed doesn't change a thing.

How can I fix my `sed` command, to change the appropriate line for the hibernate config blocks?

**edit:** It seems like I cant get `sed` groups with newlines not to work at all.

Comment: `sed` reads line by line. This means there are no newlines in the pattern space to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sed is line-based by default - to do multi-line matches you would need to add lines to the pattern space explicitly (using the `N` command for example).

Instead you could do something like this which is still line-based but steps forward to load the line of interest:

```
$ sed '/^\[Disable hibernate/{n;n;n;/^ResultActive/s/=no/=yes/;}' file.pkla
[Update already installed software]
Identity=unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
Action=org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages
ResultActive=yes

[Printer administration]
Identity=unix-group:lpadmin;unix-group:admin;unix-group:sudo
Action=org.opensuse.cupspkhelper.mechanism.*
ResultActive=yes

[Disable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Note that like your original, this will only work if the order of lines in the block can be relied on.

Comment: absolutely fantastic, thank you for the solution -  sorry my reputation is too low to mark as useful.